# BackboneJS best way to rearrange models in a collection while maintaining 0-indexed ordinal property for each model

Tags: javascript, collections, backbone.js, models

I have a problem I'm playing with here, I have a collection of BackboneJS models, each model has a 'ordinal' property that tracks its order in the collection.

**Here is my play-data**

```
var ex_group_test_data = [{

            title: 'PRE EXERCISE',
            id:         0,
            ordinal:    1,

            group_items: [{
                id:         0,
                ordinal:    0,
                title: 'item 1'
            },{
                id:         1,
                ordinal:    1,
                title: 'item 2'
            }]

        },{

            title: 'MAIN PART',
            id:         1,
            ordinal:    0,

            group_items: [{
                id:             2,
                ordinal:        0,
                title:          'item 3',
                description:    'testing descrip'
            },{
                id:         3,
                ordinal:    1,
                title: 'item 4'
            }]

        },{

            title: 'POST EXERCISE BS',
            id:         2,
            ordinal:    2,

            group_items: [{
                id:             2,
                ordinal:        0,
                title:          'item 5',
                description:    'testing descrip'
            },{
                id:         3,
                ordinal:    1,
                title: 'item 6'
            }]

        }];
```

**And here is the gist of my backbone collection**

```
        Collections.Exercise_Groups = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: Models.Exercise_Group,
            comparator: function(model){
                return model.get('ordinal');
            },
            initialize: function(){

                return this;
            }
```

Starting simple, I want to be able to take a model and move it +1 or -1 ordinal and maintain 0-indexing of all models in the collection.

Eventually I want to bring this to a level where I can drop in models or remove them from any position and still maintain my 0-indexing, or take a model and move it +/- X positions.

Anyone have an recommended ways of accomplishing this?

**EDIT 1**

I've worked out a solution, I might want to optimize this tomorrow after I actually get some sleep. It maintains the 0-indexing of the 'ordinals' of my models in my collection, whether i'm moving a model forwards or backwards relative to it's original position.

**EDIT 2**
Err actually it has errors on fringe-cases.

```
/**
             * Move model to a specified location. 
             * 
             * @param   int [model id]
             * @param   int [mew item position]
             * @return  this
             */
            move_to: function(m_id, new_pos){

                //keep within range
                if(new_pos < 0)
                    new_pos = 0;
                else if(new_pos > (this.length - 1))
                    new_pos = this.length - 1;


                var model = this.get(m_id),
                    old_pos = model.get('ordinal');


                model.set({
                    ordinal: new_pos
                });
                if(new_pos == old_pos){
                    //trigger associated events
                    this.sort();
                    return this;
                }

                //update indexes of affected models
                this.each(function(m){

                    //ordinal of current model in loop
                    var m_ordinal = m.get('ordinal');

                    //skip if this is the model we just updated
                    if(m.get('id') == m_id)
                        return;

                    if(old_pos < new_pos){
                        //moving down, ordinal is increasing

                        if(m_ordinal <= new_pos && m_ordinal != 0){
                            //this is in the range we care about
                            m.set({
                                ordinal: m.get('ordinal') - 1
                            });

                        }

                    }else if(old_pos > new_pos){
                        //moving up, ordinal is decreasing                  


                        if(m_ordinal >= new_pos && (m_ordinal != (this.length - 1))){
                            //this is in the range we care about
                            m.set({
                                ordinal: m.get('ordinal') + 1
                            });

                        }

                    }

                });

                this.sort();
                return this;

            }
```

**EDIT 3**
Okay I think I've fixed all the problems, some simple scope stuff. Here's some code I've tested pretty thoroughly and I believe it works.

```
/**
                 * Move model to a specified location. 
                 * 
                 * @param   int [model id]
                 * @param   int [mew item position]
                 * @return  this
                 */
                move_to: function(m_id, new_pos){

                    //keep within range
                    if(new_pos < 0)
                        new_pos = 0;
                    else if(new_pos > (this.length - 1))
                        new_pos = this.length - 1;


                    var model = this.get(m_id),
                        old_pos = model.get('ordinal');

                    log('old_pos ' + old_pos);
                    log('new_pos ' + new_pos);


                    model.set({
                        ordinal: new_pos
                    });
                    if(old_pos == new_pos){
                        //trigger associated events
                        this.sort();
                        return this;
                    }

                    var _this = this;
                    //update indexes of affected models
                    this.each(function(m){

                        //ordinal of current model in loop
                        var m_ordinal = m.get('ordinal');

                        //skip if this is the model we just updated
                        if(m.get('id') == m_id)
                            return;

                        if(old_pos < new_pos){
                            //moving down, ordinal is increasing

                            if(m_ordinal <= new_pos && !(m_ordinal <= 0)){
                                //this is in the range we care about
                                m.set({
                                    ordinal: m.get('ordinal') - 1
                                });

                            }

                        }else if(old_pos > new_pos){
                            //moving up, ordinal is decreasing                  
                             log('p1');

                            if(m_ordinal >= new_pos && !(m_ordinal >= (_this.length - 1))){
                                //this is in the range we care about
                                m.set({
                                    ordinal: m.get('ordinal') + 1
                                });

                            }

                        }

                    });

                    this.sort();                    
                    return this;

                }
```

**EDIT 4**

Found another bug, patched it.

```
Backbone.Collection.prototype.move_to = function(m_id, new_pos) {

    //keep within range
    if(new_pos < 0)
        new_pos = 0;
    else if(new_pos > (this.length - 1))
        new_pos = this.length - 1;


    var model = this.get(m_id),
        old_pos = model.get('ordinal');

    log('old_pos ' + old_pos);
    log('new_pos ' + new_pos);

    model.set({
        ordinal: new_pos
    });
    if(old_pos == new_pos){
        //trigger associated events
        this.sort();
        return this;
    }

    var _this = this;
    //update indexes of affected models
    this.each(function(m){

        log(m.id);

        //ordinal of current model in loop
        var m_ordinal = m.get('ordinal');

        //skip if this is the model we just updated
        if(m.get('id') == m_id)
            return;

        if(old_pos < new_pos){
            //moving down, ordinal is increasing

            if(m_ordinal <= new_pos && m_ordinal >= old_pos && !(m_ordinal <= 0)){
                //this is in the range we care about
                m.set({
                    ordinal: m.get('ordinal') - 1
                }, {
                    silent: true
                });

            }

        }else if(old_pos > new_pos){
            //moving up, ordinal is decreasing                  
             log('p1');

            if(m_ordinal >= new_pos && m_ordinal <= old_pos && !(m_ordinal >= (_this.length - 1))){
                //this is in the range we care about
                m.set({
                    ordinal: m.get('ordinal') + 1
                }, {
                    silent: true
                });

            }

        }

    });

    this.sort();                    
    return this;
};
```

Comment: So you want to say `collection.move_up(id)` or `collection.move_down(id)`? What sort of events do you expect to be generated? Just `"change:ordinal"` on the two models involved in the swaps or something on the collection as well?

Comment: I'd say a collection.move_up/down set of methods would be a start. I'm still a bit shaky on backbone. My view listens for the 'reset' event and re-renders itself accordingly already. The up/down methods would not wrap the items from the start to end of list/vice-versa.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you look at the backbone.js source code, you'll find out that for example the add method supports adding models to certain indexes with

`collectionName.add(model, {at: index});`

removing from position might need you to make a custom function to the collection, like:

```
// Your Collection

removeAt: function(options) {
  if (options.at) {
    this.remove(this.at(options.at));
  }
}
```

for +1 / -1 you can make a custom function and make use of the built-in underscore indexOf-function

```
// Your Collection

moveUp: function(model) { // I see move up as the -1
  var index = this.indexOf(model);
  if (index > 0) {
    this.remove(model, {silent: true}); // silence this to stop excess event triggers
    this.add(model, {at: index-1});
  }
}

moveDown: function(model) { // I see move up as the -1
  var index = this.indexOf(model);
  if (index < this.models.length) {
    this.remove(model, {silent: true}); // silence this to stop excess event triggers
    this.add(model, {at: index+1});
  }
}
```

This way you can also implement the moveUp and moveDown to the models themselves for more easily readable code!

```
// Your Model

moveUp: function() {
  this.collection.moveUp(this);
}

// And the same for moveDown
```

But now the index property is not saved in the models themselves. To read the index just use `collection.indexOf(model)`, but if you want to store that information in the models at all times, you could bind to the `add` and `remove` events to update all indexes when changes to the collection are made:

```
// Your collection

initialize: function(options?) {
  ...
  this.on('add remove', this.updateModelOrdinals);
  ...
},

...

updateModelOrdinals: function() {
  this.each(function(model, index) {
    this.model.set('ordinal', index);
  });
}
```

et voilà! Now you should have the functionality you need without reinventing the wheel and still keeping the 0-indexing in place with Backbone's own functionality! Sorry for getting a bit carried off, ask if I went over your head. And read [the backbone.js source](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js), you can find seriously useful stuff there!

Hope this helps!

Comment: now those functions are examples, they're not tested and i can see that some of the need some additional if-clauses to make them waterproof, but you should get the idea

Comment: Your answer helped a lot, thanks! One problem I ran into with this solution, is that the add method of the collection will do a sort if a comparator is defined, in my case resetting the order before the updateModelOrdinals method gets a chance to run. I had to name my comparator function something else and sort the collection manually. Not a big deal, but it would be nice if Backbone had the possibility to also silence the "sort" in this case.

Comment: Points for the Model's own version of this.  I've done this kind of thing a lot for things like determining the next model in a collection, and it's really handy to just be able to grab a model and call find out things about its context in a collection without having to explicitly get the collection.

Comment: Thanks this is awesome. 

For those trying this code, you don't need the 'this.model' in updateModelOrdinals each loop because model is passed in already. Just use 'model' instead. Also, I didn't have to do removeAt because remove accepted the 'at' object like add does.